# How to differentiate '-' operator from a negative number for a tokenizer

Tags: c, parsing, token

I am creating an infix expression parser, an so I have to create a tokenizer. It works well, except for one thing: I do not now how to differentiate negative number from the "-" operator.

For example, if I have:

```
23 / -23
```

The tokens should be `23`, `/` and `-23`, but if I have an expression like

```
23-22
```

Then the tokens should be `23`, `-` and `22`.

I found a dirty workaround which is if I encounter a "-" followed by a number, I look at the previous character and if this character is a digit or a ')', I treat the "-" as an operator and not a number.
Apart from being kind of ugly, it doesn't work for expressions like

```
--56
```

where it gets the following tokens: `-` and `-56` where it should get `--56`

Any suggestion?

Comment: Well the C grammar does not have negative integer constants it is all unary minus. Seems like that would be the simpler approach.

Comment: That would normally not be the job of a tokenizer, you'll have to figure this out at the syntax level.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the first example the tokens should be `23`, `/`, `-` and `23`.

The solution then is to evaluate the tokens according to the rules of associativity and precedence. `-` cannot bind to `/` but it can to 23, for example.

If you encounter `--56`,  is split into `-`,`-`,`56` and the rules take care of the problem. There is no need for special cases.

Comment: @2501: one special case which you might need to worry about is the constant `-(MAXINT+1)`, which is MININT in 2s complement architectures, but involves a constant too large for a positive integer. That means that the parser rather than the lexer needs to be responsible for error-checking, which must be done as part of constant folding in order to correctly flag out-of-bounds integer literals.